# How to access an inner function to gets its value to make a story flow

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, events

I'm trying to make a game simulation like the Voltage game just for fun, it has 4 main components, including the background, the character image, the character name and the text. I want to create a big function called startStory() which has smaller functions in there to represent different parts of the story.

How it works is that when the user clicks on the game screen the text/character name/image/background will change in order to create a story for the users. But when I tried to create the function startStory() and tried to run the inner function in it nothing happens.

Can someone help me explain why? And do you think that making different parts of the story smaller code a good idea or should I do something else? Here is my code so far

```
<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
}
.container {
  top: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70vw;
  position: relative;
}
.background {
  width: 70vw;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.character {
  width: 15vw;
  position:absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 120px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.label {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.text {
  width: 60vw;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 470px;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;

}
</style>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img class="background" src="https://img.wallpapersafari.com/desktop/1920/1080/48/39/DtNh51.jpg">
    <img class="character" src="https://www-en.voltage.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2019/07/190704_voltage_press2.jpg">
    <div class="label">Leon</div>
    <div class="text">Hi there</div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
   var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
var textHolder =  document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0]
container.addEventListener('click', startStory)

function startStory() {
  function introduceCharacter() {
    textHolder.innerHTML = 'I\'m Leon. What\'s your name?';
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that nested functions are local. So if you want to call the function introduceCharacter you have to add the event listener inside the scope of the function startStory().

```
function startStory() {

  container.addEventListener('click', introduceCharacter) //local scope.
  function introduceCharacter() {
    textHolder.innerHTML = 'I\'m Leon. What\'s your name?';
  }
}

However a better way is to simply remove the introduceCharacter function: 

function startStory() {
    textHolder.innerHTML = 'I\'m Leon. What\'s your name?'; 

}
```

In short: a function within a function is available in the scope it is declared. Nice game by the way, good luck!